# Meta: Use whatsapp API in behalf of other business

Tags: facebook, whatsapp

We have a verified business in Meta and have Whatsapp integration working with webhook.
Recently, we received a request from another business "Business A". They ask us to manage a whatsapp account in their representation giving us the phone number. They want to send messages via API and receive responses using webhook integration.
The problem is that we need to use the name "Business A" as the display name in whatsapp, and meta doesn't allowed us to use that name because it has no relationship with our business.
What can we do to use the name? Is there a way to verify that we are working with this "business A" and verify the number?
I believe this is a very simple problem, but i can't find a tutorial or something to achieve this.
Thank you in advance

We tried to register "Business A" as a new business, but they ask us for internal information about business A so we can't do that.

Comment: I have the exact same problem, did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. This seems to be possible only for BSP but I do hope there is a way to do this using cloud API.
Creating a new business under own account would work I guess provided that you can provide the supporting document from client (didnt try this yet) but also even if this work, you only have a certain limit of number of businesses you can add.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).